# PostgreSQL: How to validate and remove >'< from Input

Tags: php, postgresql

I've got a Problem. I wrote a Function in plpgsql. The Function recieves Names (in Text-Form, like "Hannes", or "Mon't Dior") from a Php-Script.

Im struggleing now with the second example: "Mon't Dior" because in plpgsql every Input-String looks like ' ... ' =>  ('Mon't Dior') with single-quotes.

So if my input now looks like 'Mon't Dior' im going to run into an Exception because there are three of them:  " ' ".

If i try to replace the single-quote within the input by the following command it only works on database-stage, but not when i call the function from my php-script.

If i pass the data from PHP to Postgres like "Mon''''t Dior", it works fine, but i want to have my Validation within the plpgsql-Function.

Do you have any proposals?

Comment: This is exactly why you should be using prepared statements

Comment: Sorry the Command i used to replace was the following:
input = replace(input, '''', ' ');